# Nagios - check_openmanage broken by latest SW update

Tags: snmp, nagios

Have been updating some servers in a small group this week. A mixture of CentOS 6.x and RHEL 5.x. In every case they are getting an updated `srvadmin-*` package and subsequently popping up in nagios with the error `(SNMP) OpenManage is not installed or is not working correctly`. Has anyone else seen this?

It appears that the plugin is using this function to test if SNMP is working:

```
#
# Checking if SNMP works by probing for "chassisModelName", which all
# servers should have
#
sub snmp_check {
    my $chassisModelName = '1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.1.300.10.1.9.1';
```

SNMP is working on my systems (used SNMPWalk to test) but this value isn't present anymore.

1. Should I look for a different value that 'all servers should have'?
2. Try to figure out where this value went?
3. Hope that the developer releases an update?
4. Other?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was on [this](http://www.op5.com/blog/support-news/known-issues/error-snmp-openmanage-installed-working-correctly/) site:

```
 sed -r -i 's/^(SNMP)=disable$/\1=enable/' /opt/dell/srvadmin/etc/srvadmin-omilcore/install.ini

 rm /opt/dell/srvadmin/var/lib/srvadmin-deng/dcsnmp.off

 srvadmin-services.sh restart

 service snmpd restart
```

Comment: Archived link: https://web.archive.org/web/20150216103425/http://www.op5.com/blog/support-news/known-issues/error-snmp-openmanage-installed-working-correctly/